# Command line approach to launching an executable through Avecto DefendPoint v5.x

Tags: windows, privileges

So, launching a commonly-used application for the first instance is easy - just shift-right-click and choose Run with Elevated Privileges.

[image]

However, that doesn't work for subsequence instances since that taskbar menu changes once the app is running.  As an alternative, but still convenient, shortcut location is the list of Pinned shorcuts on the StartMenu.  However, that menu for those items is special and never yields the avecto launch option.

[image]

I assume that the 'run with elevated privs' menu item calls some avecto process with a cmdLine arg telling it which process to elevate - however, i cannot figure out what that command is.  **Does anyone know what it is or how to discover it?**  The goal is to trigger the avecto Allow dialog - not to fully circumvent it.

There are a couple similar questions out there that suggest "avecto" is a command, but that's for an older version and has since been removed.  I'd also like to avoid adding yet another 3rd party middleman into the mix such as the "elevate" application made by Johannes.

Answer (score 2):

The following simple batch script will trigger the avecto dialog to appear.  Not supplying a value for the runas arg triggers it to request admin elevation.

```
Powershell Start 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe' -Verb Runas
```

And here's an example for Visual Studio Code

```
Powershell Start 'C:\Users\you\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe' -Verb Runas
```

And here's a unique one for running the Developer Command Prompt for visual studio - otherwise the dev prompt would automatically close as soon as it finished loading.  The /k arg will keep the resulting prompt running.

```
Powershell Start cmd -ArgumentList '/k \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat\"' -Verb Runas
```

I then created a shortcut to various .bat files and put them in my start menu Pin area to yield a way to always trigger admin each time that shortcut was clicked.

[image]

Note.. you could make a generic .bat file and pass the file location in as a shortcut arg, however the Windows 10 start menu is "smart" and eliminates duplicate shortcuts that point to the same file.  The use of separate bat files per shortcut was a workaround for that feature.